# What is the best way to initialize a state in ReactNative with custom values on a Modal?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

So, I have a specific problem where i need to initialize a state with custom values that comes from the parent component `props.theValue`. But the problem is that the `props.theValue` isn't ready when we set the state. So this line should never work:

```
const [grams, setGrams] = useState(props.theValue)
```

**The scenario:**
We have a list of food on the Parent Screen, when the users Clicks on it, it opens a modal (Like a PopUp) with some options to choose before the selected item gets manipulated

**What I tried?**

1. Set initial flag `useState(-1)` to indicate it should set the value from `props` but again, the props isn't ready in this state
2. Save the state on the parent and pass the state with the set Function to the modal. But still it doesn't seems to be right
3. useEffect but whenever i call `setGrams` it get a Loop Rendering error, also the props.theValue is still undefined at this point

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rOXY.gif):

> In this case, the both TextInput must have a initial value that comes
>   from the Parent Component and must be manipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Redux for manipulating your data between Components or you can try something like:

set a Global variable:

```
let previousObj = null
```

and then set a timeout to update your data only once, even if you set Modal invisible and Visible again

```
setTimeout(() => {
    if(food.grams != undefined && previousObj != food){
        previousObj = food
        setGrams(""+food.grams)
    }
}, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either handle it in the child with default value or don't render the component in parent until the value is available:

```
{theValue && <Component theValue={theValue} />}
```

You can use `useEffect` to update the default value as well:

```
const [grams, setGrams] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
 if (theValue) {
  setGrams(theValue);
 }
}, [theValue])
```

Comment: I Tried to handle it in the child but i need to set a state for the input to work, and whenever i set the state manually it get a loop render

Comment: The problem with useEffect is that the props.theValue is undefined at this point. Also it will get a loop render if you call setGrams there